# If solution is already built, how to run debug mode with break and unbreak debug mode in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a very large ASP.NET webforms application project, whose file takes time if I run it in Visual Studio in debug mode. Is there any way if a solution is already built to just click the run button and start debug mode without again building the solution in Visual Studio (any version)?

[image]

Comment: If project is set to debug, you then do a rebuild all. At this point clicking on the start (the browser button in your image), then compilation time should be very minimal. Is the compile time taking too long or is it the long time for the web site to spool up and display? I have some projects that take quite a long time to load and start (don't know why), but that's a seperate issue from compilation time.

Comment: Pressing 'run' in VS should only trigger recompile if some code changes have been made. But it is possible to configure the build so that this check does not work, for example if any of the build step changes the code. I would suggest building your projects one at a time, starting with the one with least dependencies, and verify that the 'build' command skips building if the code is up to date. That should help identify any problematic build-steps.